# Get rolling maximum value of a column if value of another column is "T"

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I am not very confident with lookup windows. Hence the question may seem a bit simple. But any help would be great.

I have a dataframe that captures Price movement in every second. A dummy data set is as below

```
Open    High    Low   Close
2000    5000    1300   1000
3000    3500    2000   3000
4000    4500    3500   4000
5000    5500    4500   3000
6000    6500    5500   4000
```

If the Close column is above 3000, I want to append a new column that will have the maximum value of the High column for the next n period. n may vary depending on the requirement. For example if n is 3 then the resultant data frame should be 0.

In this case, the output would look like this:

```
Open    High    Low   Close  Max_Price
2000    5000    1300   1000    0
3000    3500    2000   3000    0
4000    4500    3500   4000    6500
5000    5500    4500   3000    0
6000    6500    5500   4000    0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best way: You could use `%in%` to specifiy ID arguments that correspond to n.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number(), Max_Price = ifelse(Close > 3000 & ID == 3, max(High), 0))
```

Output:

```
 Open High  Low Close ID Max_Price
 2000 5000 1300  1000  1         0
 3000 3500 2000  3000  2         0
 4000 4500 3500  4000  3      6500
 5000 5500 4500  3000  4         0
 6000 6500 5500  4000  5         0
```

Comment: The ID column may not always have a value = 3

Comment: @NinjaR Like I said, one can use `%in%`. Try this: `df %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number(), Max_Price = ifelse(Close > 3000 & ID%in%c(3,5), max(High), 0))` You can also add a new alternative answer.